# how to pass ID in Div button which is in ajax where it have to pass Id to another page?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

below code is in my ajax which I have `comment.id` which is coming from php as unique id

```
 html += '<div class="rTableRow1"><div class="rTableHead"><input id="button1" type="button"   value="action !" />' + comment.id +'</div></div>'
```

As above full data which be shows a table

I require to click  action button where it well take to another page with ID

any one have any idea have to pass a ID in Action button which is in my Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `onclick` event-attribute to button as below:

`html += '<div class="rTableRow1"><div class="rTableHead"><input id="button1" type="button" value="action !" onclick="location.href = \'http:\\www.yoursite.com'+comment.id+'\'" />' + comment.id +'</div></div>'`

Here, `http:\\www.yoursite.com\` can be your URL and append `comment.id` as you need to pass with URL to redirect.